# Is there any way to see who has signed an msig trans and who needs to sign it?

Tags: accounts, multisig

I'm testing out the msig capabilities.   Once an msig transaction has been proposed ,  how can you determine who has already signed it and who needs to sign it?  Is there any way to notify the accounts who need to sign through the blockchain?

Comment: You can also use the hyperion to query outside the chain https://hyperion.docs.eosrio.io/v2/#v2stateget_proposals

Answer (score 0):

Both multisig-approval-tables (approvals and approvals2) contain vectors for "requested_approvals" and "provided_approvals".

See here: [msig.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.msig/include/eosio.msig/eosio.msig.hpp)

Notifications can be implemented in different ways. Probably sending a transaction containing a memo to the different accounts is the easiest way.